# How did this binomial $(x^2+3)^{-\frac 13}-\frac 23x^2(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}$ get factored into these $(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}(\frac 13x^2+3)$ factors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

This is an exercice in PRECALCULUS mathematics for calculus 7th, Section 1.3 Question 129.
And I just can't figure out how the book came up whith the answer.

I know how to factor this binomial:
$$(x^2+3)^{-\frac 13}-\frac 23x^2(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}$$
... into these factors (it may be wrong):
$$(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}  ((x^2+3)^{\frac 23}-\frac 23x^2)$$

But from there i have no idea how to continue, I'm following the basic strategy
of "pulling out" the smallest shared term $(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}$

Comment: $\frac 33 = 1$ and $(x^2 + 3)^{\frac 22} =(x^2 + 3)$ and $(x^2+3)^{\frac 23}-\frac 23x^2=(x^2+3) - 23x^2 =\frac 13 x^2 + 3$.

Comment: $-\frac 13-(-\frac 43)= 1$.  Not $\frac 23$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: As $-\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{4}{3} +1$, it follows that $(x^2+3)^{-\frac{1}{3}} = (x^2+3)^{-\frac{4}{3}}(x^2+3)$. In other words as noted in the comments already, your exponent of $\frac{2}{3}$ should be replaced by 1 as the exponent. Then continue as you would have before...

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
(x^2+3)^{-\frac{1}{3}} = (x^2+3)^{-\frac{4}{3}}(x^2+3)
$$
The original one becomes
$$
(x^2+3)^{-\frac 13}-\frac 23x^2(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}=  (x^2+3)^{-\frac{4}{3}}(x^2+3)-\frac 23x^2(x^2+3)^{-\frac 43}\\= (x^2+3)^{-\frac{4}{3}}\left (\dfrac 13x^2+3\right )
$$
We are done.

Answer (score 0):

The factorisation is wrong. The main idea is this: that when in the binomial $ab+ac,$ you factor out $a,$ then what you're in effect doing is rewriting the sum as $$a\left(\frac{ab}{a}+\frac{ac}{a}\right).$$

Hence by pulling out $(x^2+3)^{-4/3},$ you have to divide each summand by $(x^2+3)^{-4/3},$ or in other words multiply each summand by $(x^2+3)^{4/3},$ which gives you $$(x^2+3)^{-4/3}\left(x^2+3-\frac23 x^2\right),$$ from where you can continue.